# Ingress Scanner Tracking problems

Tags: gps-tracking, google-play-games

I just wanted to ask how to solve this small issue with Ingress. I have normal data connection which I use to play Ingress, however whenever I try to move to a portal, the location shown doesn't change. So I'm just curious as to what should I do for my location to normally, constantly update like it should do.

I read some similar problems and solutions like updating Google maps or resetting cashe/memory etc. But if this has its own method of solution, I'd appreciate a tip. Thanks for any tips you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices have better GPS chips, that are able to get the user's location faster. The best you can do is go to `Settings > Location` and set it to either `GPS Only` / `Device only` or `High accuracy` and in the overflow menu, tap `Advanced`, then enable `WiFi scanning`

Also, to check that it isn't a problem with Ingress, try opening Google Maps and see if your location is correct, i.e. next to the portal. If not, try reinstalling Ingress.

This use to happen with me on my old Samsung SGH-i927 - for $150 the GPS was terrible. When I upgraded to the Nexus 5 and then OnePlus 3, the difference was very noticeable.